# RadioGroup onCheckedChanged returns ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: android

Here is the RadioGroup xml file:

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/radio_group"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center">

</RadioGroup>
```

Then I programmed the buttons:

```
public class AbilityDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public static final String ATAG = "ABILITY_DIALOG";

    private String[] mAbilityList;

    public AbilityDialog() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_ability, container);
    }

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        radioGroup.removeAllViews();
        mAbilityList = getArguments().getStringArray("AbilityList");
        int selectedAbility = getArguments().getInt("SelectedAbility");
        for (int i=0; i < mAbilityList.length; i++) {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
            radioButton.setText(mAbilityList[i]);
            radioButton.setPadding(0, 0, 48, 0);
            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
        }
        radioGroup.check(selectedAbility);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(MyFragment.TAG);
                myFragment.setAbility(checkedId-1);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the main Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends DialogFragment {
public final static String TAG = "MAIN_FRAGMENT";
private int mAbility;
private String[] mAbilityList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    TextView ability = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stats_abilities);
    mAbilityList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.p184Ability);
    String abilities = mAbilityList[0];
    for (int i=1; i < mAbilityList.length; i++) {
        abilities += " / " + mAbilityList[i];
    }
    if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().getInt("Ability") != 0) {
        setAbility(getArguments().getInt("Ability") - 1);
    } else {
        mAbility = -1;
    }

    ability.setText(abilities);
    ability.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            AbilityDialog abilityDialog = new AbilityDialog();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArray("AbilityList", mAbilityList);
            bundle.putInt("SelectedAbility", mAbility);
            abilityDialog.setArguments(bundle);

            abilityDialog.show(fm, AbilityDialog.ATAG);
        }
    });



public void setAbility(int ability) {
    mAbility = ability;
    if (mAbility != -1) {
        TextView pokemonAbility = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.stats_abilities);
        pokemonAbility.setText(mAbilityList[ability]);
    }
}

private void closeFragment() {
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
}
```

I hope there are enough information now.

Edit: It doesn't seem to be compilable. I'll put up more codes if the problem still can't be diagnosed.

Comment: What does `MyFragment.setItem()` look like?

Comment: I have edited the post above to include this function. Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

My first guess, though I have no way to check it without more of your code, is that the view is not being recreated and therefore you are adding more and more radio buttons to the group instead of it restarting each time.

You can force it to clear all of the buttons with `radioGroup.removeAllViews()`

Add that to the start of the `onViewCreated(...)` and see what happens.

Comment: I thought about that as well but it didn't work. The pop-up dialog also only shows three options (expected) instead of 6

Comment: Please allow me 10 minutes I'll try to put up the compilable snippet

Comment: It is possible that the views are simply hidden though. Try adding that line just to see. At worst it is redundant.

Comment: I have just added the line as indicated above but the problem still persists. I have provided a bigger snippet but it's still not compilable yet. Please let me know if you need more codes

Comment: That is the extent of my ability without having a debugger, sorry. I hope that you can find a solution.